# I need to create new sheets based on unique names found in column A. Current Code generates excess data in certain sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have the following code so far based on questions asked by other people.

I have a set of names listed in column A, and 216 columns and 9725 rows of data.

Currently using the following code I get the new sheets created except along with the unique names and its relevant data I get many cells filled with "#N/A".

In certain cases, the name Bob for example will be populated in a new sheet called Bob but the first column will have Bob and all relevant data and once all Bobs rows are shown it is follower with many rows with #N/A and all columns with #N/A.

In other cases the sheet will be created for Charles and all of Charles data will be listed, then many rows of #N/A and then all of the master-data including other peoples names which I need to avoid.

I want each individual sheet to only have the info based on the name of the person on that sheet. All of the data gets copied as I verified the number of accurate cells that get populated yet I get these #N/A cells and duplicated extra data and I'm not sure how to stop it from being populated? Any help in cleaning the code would be appreciated!!

Code:

```
Sub CopyDataFromReportToIndividualSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("FormulaMSheet2")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MyRange As Range

Worksheets("FormulaMSheet2").Activate

LastRow = Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' stop processing if we don't have any data
If LastRow < 2 Then Exit Sub


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' SortMasterList LastRow, ws
CopyDataToSheets LastRow, ws
ws.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub SortMasterList(LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet)
ws.Range("A2:BO" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A1") 
', Key2:=ws.Range("B1")
End Sub
Sub CopyDataToSheets(LastRow As Long, src As Worksheet)
Dim allAgentNameCells As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Series As String
Dim SeriesStart As Long
Dim SeriesLast As Long

Set allAgentNameCells = Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
SeriesStart = 2
Series = Range("A" & SeriesStart).Value

For Each cell In allAgentNameCells

    If cell.Value <> " " And cell.Value <> "" Then
        ' Condition ` And cell.Value <> "" ` added for my testdata. If you don't need this, please remove.

        ' Current Row's Series not SPACE

        If cell.Value <> Series Then
            SeriesLast = cell.Row - 1
            CopySeriesToNewSheet src, SeriesStart, SeriesLast, Series
            Series = cell.Value
            SeriesStart = cell.Row
        End If
    End If
Next

'' copy the last series
SeriesLast = LastRow
CopySeriesToNewSheet src, SeriesStart, SeriesLast, Series

End Sub

Sub CopySeriesToNewSheet(src As Worksheet, Start As Long, Last As Long, name As String)

Dim tgt As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As Range

If (SheetExists(name)) Then
    MsgBox "Sheet " & name & " already exists. " _
    & "Please delete or move existing sheets before" _
    & " copying data from the Master List.", vbCritical, _
    "Time Series Parser"
    End
Else
   If Series = " " Then
      End
   End If

End If

Worksheets("FormulaMSheet2").Activate

' Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).name = name
Worksheets("FormulaMSheet2").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.name = name

Set tgt = Sheets(name)

' copy data from src to tgt
tgt.Range("A2:BO2" & Last - Start + 2).Value = src.Range("A" & Start & ":BO" & Last).Value


End Sub

Function SheetExists(name As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Variant

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.name = name Then

        SheetExists = True
        Exit Function

    End If
Next

SheetExists = False

End Function
```

Comment: In the Sub `CopySeriesToNewSheet` , what is the initial value for `Series` ? And you did not declare the variable in that sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed at the following site: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006_5.htm .

I figured if anyone else was looking for similar code it would help taking a look at the site.

Answer (score 0):

You need replace the

```
tgt.Range("A2:BO2" & Last - Start + 2).Value = src.Range("A" & Start & ":BO" & Last).Value
```

to

```
src.Range("A" & Start & ":BO" & Last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=tgt.Range("A2:BO2" & Last - Start + 2)
```

Comment: Hi Keon, I tried replacing the code. It causes new sheets by each name to be created, but all the data on the master-data gets copied onto each newly created sheet rather than just the data relevant to the name of the new sheet. So the code stops functioning as I need to.